# Destructor being called multiple times

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, destructor

i am trying to check how **new** , **init** and **del** works and was running below mentioned code , what caught my attention is destructor is being called twice and i don't know the exact reason of it, Can anyone help with it?

```
class Example:

    # creation of new instance
    def __new__(cls):
        print("example created", object.__new__(cls))
        return object.__new__(cls)

    # Initializing
    def __init__(self):
        print("Example Instance.")

    # Calling destructor
    def __del__(self):
        print("Destructor called, Example deleted.")

obj = Example()
del obj
```

Comment: You create two instances in `__new__`, one in the print and one that you return

Comment: thanks got it , instead of assigning it to variable and then using it in return and print i created 2 instances which ended up calling destructor twice @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

From geeksforgeeks:

> The __del__() method is a known as a destructor method in Python. It is called when all references to the object have been deleted i.e when an object is **garbage collected**. Note : **A reference to objects is also deleted when the object goes out of reference** or when the program ends.

Python automatically manages memory for you using reference counting and garbage collector. That is, references unnecessary are being automatically deleted.

So you need to create it explicitly to avoid this behavior.

```py
class Example:
   instance = ""

    # creation of new instance
    def __new__(cls):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        print("example created", instance)
        return instance

    # Initializing
    def __init__(self):
        print("Example Instance.")

    # Calling destructor
    def __del__(self):
        print("Destructor called, Example deleted.")
```

result:

```
>>> obj = Example()
example created <__main__.Example object at 0x7fd0b3efa5b0>
Example Instance.
>>> del obj
Destructor called, Example deleted.
>>>
```